# All of sudden gulp command not recognizing

Tags: spfx, nodejs, gulp

I made windows update on this Sunday. From that point, I am not able to execute gulp commands. I am not sure if there is any relation between windows update and gulp command. I am getting below error.
[image]
I have installed gulp again by `npm install gulp -g`. I have restarted my machine and tried. But still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Often, it’s due to location ref issues (path to the modules when installed globally), so when you run gulp it does not know where to look (can be caused by system update, nvm bugs (if you use it), etc.

You can try this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027551/gulp-command-not-found-error-after-installing-gulp/41419949

Witch propose many solutions, but two stands out (upvotes):

One:
npm install -g gulp-cli

Two:

1. Create an environmental variable called NODE_PATH
2. Set it to: %AppData%\npm\node_modules or %AppData%\npm on windows 8-10
3. Close CMD, and Re-Open to get the new Environment Variables

Or you can simply refer to gulp in the directory: `.\node_modules\.bin\gulp` to run gulp if you have it installed there.